# superuser rss feed not displaying on Windows7 gadget

Tags: support, status-completed, rss

Hi,

I searched around superuser and could not find similar question. Many users have problem to "display the gadget", but my problem is that the gadget showed up properly, but only few of my feeds have content. None of my feeds from superuser showed up.

[image: This is what happened with superuser feed]

This is what happened with all superuser feed.

[image: This is a normal rss feed with contents]

This is a normal rss feed with contents.

I tried with default rss feed widget, also the "Feed Reader" widget. Both of them won't display rss feed. I should also mention that I have all the rss feed go to Outlook2010 first, and seems like it will automatically add to IE(?) As it automatically showed up in the gadget.

Comment: So just to clarify @Patrick, are you only seeing this problem specifically with the SuperUser RSS feed, or with other sites' RSS feeds as well?

Comment: I seem this problem also with stackoverflow's RSS feed. Other feeds I have are fine. I will try a few others tonight.

Comment: Can you insert a link to the RSS feed in question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this still a problem, or is it resolved? We aren't aware of any RSS issues at this time.